# Spring Security & ExtJS - redirecting to login page on session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, extjs, spring-security

I am using ExtJS with Spring MVC/Security. I want the user to be redirected to the login page when the session has expired, and I gave this in the Spring security application context -

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp"></session-management>
```

But since the calls to the server are all AJAX based, the redirection does not happen.
Please suggest the best way to implement this.
I have a custom `UserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` implemented for AJAX login:

```
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler srh = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(srh);
        srh.setRedirectStrategy(new RedirectStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, String s) throws IOException {
                // do nothing, no redirect
            }
        });
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);

        HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(
         response);
        Writer out = responseWrapper.getWriter();
        out.write("{success:true}");
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930646/session-timeout-response-in-ajax

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to mold the following to override all ajax requests to test for a timed out session response and handle it accordingly:

```
var origHandleResponse = Ext.data.Connection.prototype.handleResponse;
Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, {
handleResponse : function(response){
    var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    if (<test for response that means the session timed out>)
    {
            var login = new Ext.Window({
                plain: true,
                closeAction: 'hide',
                modal: true,
                title: "Login timed out, please log in.",
                width: 400,
                autoHeight: true,
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    id: 'login-form',
                    items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Username',
                        name: 'username'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        inputType: 'password',
                        fieldLabel: 'Password',
                        name: 'password'
                    }]
                }],
                buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    handler: function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('login-form').getForm().submit({url: '<login url>'});
                        login.hide();
                    }
                }]
            });
            login.show();
    }
    //else (optional?)
    origHandleResponse.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

});